# NgPickDateTime display Military Time

Tags: datetimepicker, angular5

I'm using the ng-pick-datetime picker for my application.  I want the selected time to show in 24hr (15:00 instead of 3:00 pm).  When the picker opens the time is displayed in the picker correctly, but once selected it changes it to 12hr time format.  Is there a way to set the selected time to show in 24 hour time instead of 12 hour?

[image]
[image]

Here is a link to the picker I'm using:
[ng-pick-datetime](https://danielykpan.github.io/date-time-picker/)

Answer (score 4):

Put hour12: false to custom format, and just working see code below:

```
export const MY_NATIVE_FORMATS = {
  fullPickerInput: {year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric', hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', hour12: false},
  datePickerInput: {year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric', hour12: false},
  timePickerInput: {hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', hour12: false},
  monthYearLabel: {year: 'numeric', month: 'short'},
  dateA11yLabel: {year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric'},
  monthYearA11yLabel: {year: 'numeric', month: 'long'},
};

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {provide: OWL_DATE_TIME_FORMATS, useValue: MY_NATIVE_FORMATS},
  ]
})
```

Comment: Thanks @Temp its really helpfull for me but in input field i also want to show seconds can you help me

Answer (score 0):

I know this was posted too long, but here is my solution. It's more of a hack as I found that it's not possible to change the format directly.

So I created another input field which will show the time in 24-hour format, while the original input which will have the functionality to open the time picker will not be visible.

HTML:

```
<div class="position-relative time-parent">
          <input type="text" class="form-control original-time-field" 
                  placeholder="Eg: 06:55 (24-Hour)" 
                  name="timeOriginal" 
                  [(ngModel)]="timeOrig" 
                  [readonly]="true" />

          <input type="text" class="form-control picker-time-field" 
                  name="depTime" #depTime="ngModel"
                  [(ngModel)]="timeObj" 
                  [owlDateTime]="dtdp" 
                  [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dtdp" 
                  (dateTimeChange)="onTimeChange($event)" 
                  [readonly]="true"
                  required />
          <owl-date-time #dtdp [pickerType]="'timer'" [hour12Timer]="false"></owl-date-time>
        </div>
```

CSS(Note: below is SASS) :

```
.time-parent {
        .original-time-field,
        .picker-time-field {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }

        .original-time-field {
            z-index: 2;
        }

        .picker-time-field {
            z-index: 3;
            opacity: 0;
        }
    }
```

JS :

```
onTimeChange(evnt) {
    this.timeOrig = evnt.value.getHours() + ':' + evnt.value.getMinutes();
  }
```

This worked fine for me, as this gives you flexibility to show time as you like.